# set a variable as stringvar.get()

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.4

I have issue I have a code that makes a select query :

```
loginquery = "SELECT * from User "
loginquery = loginquery + "WHERE UserName="+ loginVar.get() +" AND Password="+ passVar.get()+""
```

Issue with that is that the result is 
SELECT * from User WHERE UserName= AND Password=

How do I fix that?

EDIT:::::

This is my code

```
loginquery = ("SELECT * from User "
              "WHERE UserName=%s AND Password=%s")
bobby = (loginVar.get(),passVar.get())
```

and I do

```
(query.execute(loginquery % bobby)
```

my print result is:

> SELECT * from User WHERE UserName=usernameentered AND Password=passwordentered

However the mysql connector comes up with this error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND Password=' at line 1
```

Why is that?

Comment: can you be more specific please

Comment: @davi he's talking about a specific kind of SQL attack you're making yourself vulnerable too. If a malicious user has credentials and knows your table name, he can set `loginVar` to his username, and `passVar` to `<password>; DROP TABLE <tablename>;` and your code will drop the whole table.

Comment: I understand that but for now I am not trying to make it secure I am just trying to make it work

Comment: Well you haven't ended your query with a semicolon, so that's the problem....

Comment: Nope ended I just ended it with semi colon and same error @Adam Smith

Answer (score 0):

You should add quotation marks around string literals:

```
loginquery = ("SELECT * from User "
              "WHERE UserName='%s' AND Password='%s'")
```

Comment: Nope all it does it adds quotes on top of that  so the result is : SELECT * from User WHERE UserName='' AND Password=''

Comment: When I add those instead of giving me that error it skips me to failure straight away  'def LoginPress():

    if(query.execute(loginquery % bobby)):
        print(loginquery % bobby)
        db.commit()
        print ("LOGGED IN!")
    else:
        print(loginquery % bobby)
        db.commit()
        print ("Failure!!")
'

Comment: It means that your `loginVar.get()` and `passVar.get()` methods return empty strings. This has nothing to do with the fact that you need quotes.

Comment: I managed to to the appropiate input which is : SELECT * from User WHERE UserName=asdasd AND Password=asd  However i still get this error now 'mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'asdasd' in 'where clause' ' @Selcuk

Comment: That's because you omit the quotes. Without quotes the database server thinks that it is a column name.

Comment: That helped a little now instead of getting an error the query doesn't find the record by that I mean it goes straight to Failure! I double checked if I am entering the correct information but it still doesn't work @Selcuk